# Cannot use *ngFor for a two-dimensional array in Angular

Tags: json, angular, ngfor

I saw many similar questions but the solutions there didn't work for me. I want to display orders in Angular.

I receive clients' orders in Json format from Spring. Like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "orderProducts": [],
        "numberOfProducts": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "orderProducts": [
            {
                "quantity": 4,
                "product": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "brand": "apple",
                    "name": "iphone11",
                    "categoryId": 1
                }
            }
        ],
        "numberOfProducts": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "orderProducts": [
            {
                "quantity": 9,
                "product": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "brand": "apple",
                    "name": "iphone11",
                    "categoryId": 1
                }
            },
            {
                "quantity": 6,
                "product": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "brand": "xiaomi",
                    "name": "Note10",
                    "categoryId": 1
                }
            },
            {
                "quantity": 1,
                "product": {
                    "id": 6,
                    "brand": "cccccccccccccccc",
                    "name": "cccccccccccccc",
                    "categoryId": 1
                }
            }
        ],
        "numberOfProducts": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "orderProducts": [
            {
                "quantity": 5,
                "product": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "brand": "apple",
                    "name": "iphone11",
                    "categoryId": 1
                }
            }
        ],
        "numberOfProducts": 1
    }
]
```

So i created a class in Angular to accept it.

**db-orders.ts**

```
export class DbOrders {
    id: number;
    orders: ProductOrder[];
    numberOfProducts: number;

    constructor(orders: ProductOrder[]){
        this.orders = orders;
    }
}
```

**product-order.ts**

```
export class ProductOrder {
    product: Product;
    quantity: number;

    constructor(product: Product, quantity: number){
        this.product = product;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

**product.ts**

```
export class Product {
    id: number;
    brand: string;
    name: string;
    category: ProductCategory;

    constructor(){}

}
```

Here is a service class.

**order.service.ts**

```
export class OrderService {

  private orderUrl: string = 'http://localhost:8080/orders';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  saveOrder(order: ProductOrders) {
    console.log("Hello")
    return this.http.post<ProductOrders>(this.orderUrl, order);
}

public findOrders(): Observable<DbOrders[]> {
  return this.http.get<DbOrders[]>(this.orderUrl);
}
```

}

**order-list.component.ts**

```
export class OrderListComponent implements OnInit {

  receivedOrders: DbOrders[] = [];
 
  constructor(private orderService: OrderService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.orderService.findOrders().subscribe(
      data =>{
        this.receivedOrders = data;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

**order-list.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let receivedOrder of receivedOrders">
   <p>Number of Products in the order: {{receivedOrder.numberOfProducts}}</p> 
 
     <div *ngFor="let order of receivedOrder.orders">
        <h1>Product name: {{ order.product.name }}</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this case, only the number of products is displayed,nothing else:

[image: Screenshot]

I tried to add a toArray method:

```
<div *ngFor="let order of toArray(receivedOrder.orders)">


ngOnInit(): void {
    this.orderService.findOrders().subscribe(
      data =>{
        this.receivedOrders = data;
      }
    );
  }

  toArray(orders: object) {
    return Object.keys(orders).map(key => orders[key])
  }
```

Doesn't work.

Also i tried to add indexes.

```
<div *ngFor="let receivedOrder of receivedOrders; let i=index"">
       <p>Number of Products in the order: {{receivedOrder.numberOfProducts}}</p> 
     
         <div *ngFor="let order of receivedOrder.orders; let j=index"">
            <h1>Product name: {{ order.product.name }}</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Doesn't work either.

What is my mistake? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a few problems. Firstly, your data structure does not match your classes.

E.g. your `ProductOrder` object should have an array of `OrderProduct` objects as that is what your data has.

Your constructor for `ProductOrder` never gets called because you are no instantiating the object from the class.

In simple terms, change your html to this for it to work:

```
<div *ngFor="let receivedOrder of data; let i=index">
    <p>Number of Products in the order: {{receivedOrder.numberOfProducts}}</p>

    <div *ngFor=" let order of receivedOrder.orderProducts; let j=index">
        <h1>Product name: {{ order.product.name }}</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can also find a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vgwmm3?file=src/app/app.component.html) on StackBlitz.

Comment: Thank you! Inside ProductOrder class i changed "orders" to "orderProducts" like you wrote. And it works now. And regarding the ProductOrder constructor. I don't need it, because i get data from Spring, right?

Comment: No, it's because you never call the constructor. You're classes are basically there for type safety, so you get compile time errors.